# C# preventing combox selectionChanged event from recalling itself

Tags: c#, .net

I have this event handler which I need to, under certain conditions change it's selected item
in code. When I do this it will recall the handler due to being changed and re-execute. How can I prevent this?

```
MessageBox.Show("Must have a repair report.", "No Report");
txtLocation.SelectedItem = MAIN_BACKGROUND.UserName; //here it recalls itself as I return its value to what it was before the change
```

Comment: @AlexFarber -- Does that incur unnecessary overhead, though?

Comment: @roryap I agree, this would probably be a lot more costly

Comment: I had to do this on the form load sequence, tried in the handler and had issues. Using Boolean method below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a global boolean value to stop the event body from performing its substantive work during the "inner" event handler:

```
private bool _alreadyChanging = false;

private void txtLocation_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_alreadyChanging)
    {
        _alreadyChanging = true;
        MessageBox.Show("Must have a repair report.", "No Report");
        txtLocation.SelectedItem = MAIN_BACKGROUND.UserName;
        _alreadyChanging = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to handle the logic for skipping the change inside the event handler. This is no way to stop the event from firing again.

```
if(txtLocation.SelectedItem == MAIN_BACKGROUND.UserName)
    return;

MessageBox.Show("Must have a repair report.", "No Report");
txtLocation.SelectedItem = MAIN_BACKGROUND.UserName;
```

Edit:
Adding an example where you use a boolean flag to accomplish the same thing

```
public Class class
{

    private bool _shouldHandle = true;
    public void EventHandler(object Sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(_shouldHandle)
      {
        _shouldHandle = false;
        //make change
        _shouldHandle = true;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: obviously I am not sure what the logic for your specific case should be, but this is a best guess based on what little you have put down.

Comment: `class` will only handle every other event. `_shouldHandle = true` should be part of your `if(_shouldHandle)` block to ensure that the handled event releases the lock on handling future events only when it has completed.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have had the ComboBox.SelectionChangeCommitted event since NET 1.1 
to prevent exactly that problem.

That event only fire when the *user* changes the combobox. No need to unsubscribe
from any event or use a boolean value.

Comment: I looked into this event, seems to be a very viable solution to what I needed. I should have mentioned that I was using WPF, which from what I can tell this does not exist in. Thank you for your suggestion I will make use of this in my form apps.